# How to set custom search paths for the terminfo database when building ncurses from source

Tags: search, path, ncurses, terminfo

How do I set custom search paths for the terminfo database when building ncurses from source?

To be more specific, how do I force the primary directory to be searched in '~/.terminfo'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [terminfo manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/terminfo/):

> Fetching Compiled Descriptions
>         If the environment variable TERMINFO is set, it is interpreted  as  the
>         pathname  of  a  directory  containing the compiled description you are
>         working on.  Only that directory is searched.
>
> ```
>   If TERMINFO is not set, the ncurses version of the terminfo reader code
>   will  instead  look  in  the  directory  $HOME/.terminfo for a compiled
>   description.
> ```

You may need to consult the manpage for information on how to compile the terminfo file.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Define the `--datadir` flag in `configure`, like:

```
configure --datadir=/usr/customshare
```

Read the notes in INSTALL file located in the root of ncurses files:

> ...
>
> The location of the terminfo is set indirectly by the "--datadir"
>   configure option, e.g., /usr/share/terminfo, given a datadir of
>   /usr/share.  You may want to override this if you are installing
>   ncurses libraries in nonstandard locations, but wish to share the
>   terminfo database.
>
> ...
>
> --with-terminfo-dirs=XXX
>   Specify a search-list of terminfo directories which will be compiled
>   into the ncurses library (default: DATADIR/terminfo)