# How does ncurses search for terminal descriptions

Tags: ncurses, terminfo, ubuntu-17.10

I'm building ncurses 6.1 from source for some reasons. First I configure the sources with

```
./configure
```

and then I build it with

```
make
```

both without arguments. When I try to run tests I get the error message

```
Error opening terminal: xterm-256color.
```

on my local system (Ubuntu 17.10) and

```
Error opening terminal: xterm
```

on the build server (Jenkins Docker container).

I found out that this build is looking for terminal descriptions in `/usr/share/terminfo/`. There are many descriptions but no `xterm-256color` on my local system. On the build server the folder `/usr/share/terminfo/` is empty. I found `xterm-256color` and `xterm` at `/lib/terminfo`. When I install ncurses with package manager (apt for Ubuntu 17.10), it works. So I assume that this package chooses the right path. I copied `xterm-256color` resp. `xterm` from `/lib/terminfo` to `/usr/share/terminfo/` and my build works on both systems now. Why do two different paths exist and why do these two versions of ncurses choose two different paths? I need a conan package of ncurses that works out of the box without copying description files.

This could be a duplicate of:
[How to set custom search paths for the terminfo database when building ncurses from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158602/how-to-set-custom-search-paths-for-the-terminfo-database-when-building-ncurses-f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the summary at the end of `configure` (which isn't shown in the question).  But running `infocmp -D` will show the directories that `infocmp` would use when looking for descriptions.

You can modify the behavior using the [`TERMINFO`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO) and [`TERMINFO_DIRS`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO_DIRS) environment variables.

The `/lib/terminfo` is Debian-specific (Ubuntu doesn't provide any changes for ncurses; they simply recompile the Debian packages: most Ubuntu bug reports for ncurses deal with their problems in doing that).

Debian by default installs someone's notion of a minimal terminal database in that directory.  Install `ncurses-term` to get a full terminal database.

By the way, compiling and installing ncurses on Debian/Ubuntu/other systems with ncurses already installed runs a risk of breaking the existing libraries which are used (for example) by `bash` and other utilities that you probably need.

Comment: Is it possible to change the behavior in with arguments to `configure` or `make`. As I said I want to use the library without changing the systems, no environment variables or copying of descriptions. I'm not installing my own build. I use conan, so the library is in the jenkins home an conan sets the include and library paths.

Comment: `./configure --datadir=/lib` and `make` works for me. Your information lead to the correct post in SO.