# Is it possible to configure ncurses to hardcode a terminfo path relative to the executable instead of an absolute path?

Tags: c++, ncurses, terminfo

I am building ncurses from source (and then linking my application to it) as part of the build process for my application, and I have observed that the built binaries have the absolute path of the custom `terminfo` hardcoded into them.

This absolute path does not make sense in the deployed environment, forcing the user to set `TERMINFO` before the program is able to run.

**Is there some configuration option to force ncurses to hardcode a path relative to the executable instead?**

Alternately, is there a more "standard" way to deploy simple command line applications with custom terminfo libraries, if I wish to avoid heavyweight tools like Docker?

---

Here are the commands I use to download and build ncurses:

```
pushd lib
curl -L -o ncurses-6.3.tar.gz         https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-6.3.tar.gz
tar xf ncurses-6.3.tar.gz
pushd ncurses-6.3
./configure --prefix=`pwd`/dist --enable-widec && make && make install
popd
popd
```

Here's a minimum program:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(){
  initscr();
}
```

Here's the command I use to compile it:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -o MWE MWE.cc  -Ilib/ncurses-6.3/dist/include  lib/ncurses-6.3/dist/lib/libncursesw_g.a
```

Here's how I found the hardcoded path:

```
strings MWE | grep ncurses
/Users/merlin2011/Code/MWE/lib/ncurses-6.3/dist/share/terminfo
```

Comment: Am I missing something or are you _telling_ it to hardcode that path? --prefix=`pwd`

Comment: Oh that's an interesting hypothesis. 
I thought that path only affected where the files lives, not the hardcoding of the terminfo path.

Comment: I can try to change that to a relative path, but then I'd imagine it's relative to the `lib`  directory instead of the binary's path...

Comment: That's not so much an hypothesis, but what is explained in the install instructions that come with it. It is an absolute path where terminfo will be installed. It sets some other absolute paths as well.

Comment: Okay, I guess I'm stuck with using a wrapper script to set TERMINFO in the deployed environment. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40269919/15381660

Comment: the answer literally came as an auto-related question. I don't have the rep, but I suggest you close this as a duplicate

Comment: This answers your question:  [How to set custom search paths for the terminfo database when building ncurses from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158602/how-to-set-custom-search-paths-for-the-terminfo-database-when-building-ncurses-f).  Use `configure --help`, or read `INSTALL`.